# set css with JSON array values

Tags: javascript, css, json, reactjs

I have a React class that renders a set of html elements from a JSON array of objects. The object keys set the classnames, and the object key values set the inner text.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Maps.css";
import df3 from "./data/df3.json"
import sample from "./data/sample.json"

class Maps extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const data = df3;
    this.state = data
  }
  renderDiv = () => {
    var df4 = df3["ds"];
    return df4.map(v => {
      return Object.keys(v).map((space) => {
        return (
          <div className={space}>
            {v[space][0]}
          </div>
        );
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div id="Maps">{this.renderDiv()}</div>;
  }

}

export default Maps
```

What I would like to do, is return something like this, where the style is set by the object value (for example, scaling the div):

```
return (
          <div className={space}
               style={{transform:'scale({v[value][0]},{v[value][0]})'}}>
            {v[space][0]}
          </div>
        );
```

Any help, as always, is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string literals to form up your styling :

```
style={{transform:`scale(${v[value][0]},${v[value][0]})`}}>
```

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: this seems to delete almost all of the elements.

Comment: Well that simply means that your objecte doesn't contain the right scaling value